# Как я могу заменить один дистрибутив linux на другой?

Tags: linux, bios, пк

На ноутбуке стоит linux ROSA, ее нужно заменить на linux Slax, но не зависимо от настроек BIOS первой всегда запускается система, а не моя загрузочная флешка. Как я могу это исправить?
Мне не нужна ROSA и нет важных файлов, поэтому есть возможность полностью удалить систему. BIOS стоит InsydeH2O.

Comment: Для начала следует создать загрузочную флешку.

Comment: А точно флэшка создалась корректно? На другой тачке пашет? Попробуй через `Ventoy`.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно можно поменять загрузочный диск кнопкой f9, f10, f11 при включении питания.

Если все равно не находит флешку, то попробуйте записать на неё другой загрузчик. Например Rufus ставит свой.

Вы создавали флешку через `dd if=iso of=/dev/sdb`?

Comment: Нет, я создавал через программу balenaEtcher.